# twitter4j 4.x系が動かない

Tags: java, twitter, spring, maven, twitter4j

開発環境はmaven, spring, java7, Androidアプリではないです。
JUNITでTESTしましたが、JSONのレスポンスが返ってきませんでした。

twitter4j.properties

```
oauth.consumerKey=略
oauth.consumerSecret=略
oauth.accessToken=略
oauth.accessTokenSecret=略
```

TwitterService.java

```
@Autowired
private Twitter twitter;

/**
 * Tweetを検索する
 * @param keywords
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public Set<Status> getTweet(String slice, Integer limit, String keywords) throws Exception {
    Set<Status> results = new HashSet<Status>();

    Query query = new Query(keywords);
    query.setLang("ja");

    // ループ回数
    if (limit > 1500) limit = 1500;
    int roupe = limit / 200;
    int limited = limit % 200;

    Long finalId = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= roupe; i++) {
        query.setCount(i == roupe ? limited : 200);
        if (finalId != null) query.setMaxId(finalId);
        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        finalId = result.getSinceId();
        results.addAll(result.getTweets());
    }
    return results;
}
```

下記の行でNullPoが発生します。

```
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

以下、スタックトレースです。

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at twitter4j.QueryResultJSONImpl.(QueryResultJSONImpl.java:43)
    at twitter4j.JSONImplFactory.createQueryResult(JSONImplFactory.java:145)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:255)
    at jp.dip.略.getTweet(TwitterService.java:62)
    at jp.dip.melonslv.TwitterWrappHelperTest.testツイート取得(TwitterTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

大したことはしていないはずなんですがなぜ動かないのでしょうか。
twitter4jご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Comment: ＠Autowiredでインスタンスを取得していると思われる Twitter のインスタンスは取得できていますか？＠Autowiredするインスタンスは、Springの設定が必要となりますが、それについては記載していますでしょうか。

Comment: 設定ファイル等肥大化しているので省略しましたが、インスタンスがあることはデバッグで確認しました。

Comment: 上記コード、当方の環境では正常に実行されました。
これはカンなのですが、プロキシサーバーでtwitterへのアクセスがブロックされていたりしませんか？
(ちなみにnullになっているのは以下のhandleRequestメソッドの戻り値かと思います)
https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/internal-http/java/twitter4j/HttpClientImpl.java#L82

Comment: Proxyが悪さをしていました・・・ありがとうございました！

Comment: @omarun 本質問が解決済みであることが他のユーザにも分かりやすくするため、ご自身で回答を記入して承認して頂けると思います。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

上記コード、当方の環境では正常に実行されました。 これはカンなのですが、プロキシサーバーでtwitterへのアクセスがブロックされていたりしませんか？ (ちなみにnullになっているのは以下のhandleRequestメソッドの戻り値かと思います) 
https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/internal-http/java/twitter4j/HttpClientImpl.java#L82